# Word that describes devices which are combinations or two other devices?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering if there is a term that describes any given physical device that is a "spiritual" combination of two other devices. Meaning, it mimics the form and function of both parent devices.

Examples:

- Spork (combination of a spoon and a fork)
- Halberd (combination of a staff and an axe)
- Calculator Watch (combination of a calculator and a watch)

To explain via analogy, "*Portmanteau* is to words as ***_*__*_*_** is to devices"

Comment: Perhaps this one is a bit of a stretch, but you might be able to use _Swiss army knife_, in a simile, or as a metaphor. That's what [this headline writer did](http://mashable.com/2013/10/10/gecko-tag/).

Comment: 'Batpig' would more probably be called a _chimera_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth haha I didn't even think of the connection there, it's just what I call my French Bulldog.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That **is** clever! Thankfully, batpigandme a.k.a. batpig is the very opposite of chimera-like. Hi batpigandme! It is I, Ellie!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would propose the term *hybrid*:

> **[hybrid](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/hybrid)** - a thing made by combining two different elements; a mixture

By analogy from agriculture, it could casually be called a *cross*, as in a *cross between A and B* where A and B (… Z) are its components.

> A [mattock](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aCutter_mattock.jpg) is a cross between a pick and an adze.

In certain fields, notably music and web-based software applications, the term *mashup* has currency. A song *mashup* combines two or more pre-recorded songs into a new composition. A web mashup is typically a presentation combining data from multiple sources, for example displaying the sources of Tweets on a Google Map. But only the most vacuous analyst or marketer would call a spork or a mattock a *mashup*.

A more derisive term would be *bastard*, which connotes some imperfection in or prejudice against either the lineage or the combination, and is mildly offensive in some quarters. *MacOS is the bastard of the Mach kernel and BSD.*

Answer (score 2):

A traditional term, at least for machinery, is **mule**.

Samuel Crompton invented the ['spinning mule'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_mule) or 'mule jenny' in 1779, so called because it is a hybrid of Arkwright's water frame and James Hargreaves' spinning jenny in the same way that mule is the product of crossbreeding a female horse with a male donkey. The ['muledozer'](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/VINTAGE-BRITAINS-MODEL-No-9535-MULEDOZER-VN-MIB-/400511650232) was / is a [hybrid standard agricultural tractor / dozer](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/A2A/records.aspx?cat=007-amd_2&cid=1077#1077).

The noun is also used attributively for at least one one hybrid [item of furniture](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5730).

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is "hybrid device", although it's not one word.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [phablet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phablet) would meet the requirements of being a

> a physical device that is a combination of two other devices

phone + tablet = phablet. Granted, it's of relatively recent coinage.

Comment: It's definitely an example of one, is there a generic term for this though?

Answer (score 0):

"Compound" or "Combination (combo)" seem to fit this description.

Also, the prefix "multi" is sometimes slapped onto other words to show relationships similar to what you've described.

"Multi-tool" one tool that has multiple functionalities, usually because it is the combination of multiple tools.

"Multiplex" a movie theater that is made up of multiple screens.